# How to insert string and array values in table using codigniter

Tags: php, sql

I have A **multi-dimension** array, that **multi-dimension** array has four arrays each array has two string values that should be inserted for table's column name.

But my problem is, four arrays of one array has two arrays, that has one array, that one array has two string values, so my question is how to insert the values of **multi-dimension** array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [stu_ans_id] => 1
            [stu_answer] => True
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [stu_ans_id] => 2
            [stu_answer] => B
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [stu_ans_id] => 3
            [stu_answer] => hi
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [stu_ans_id] => 4
            [stu_answer] => Array
                (
                    [2] => B
                    [3] => C
                )

        )

)
```

actually this four type arrays are quiz question answers, First 3 arrays are textbox and radio buttons but that last array is checkbox value so it is complicated to me so please help to solve this issue

```
 public function add_stu_ans()
```

{

```
      $id = $values['stu_ans_id'] = $this->input->post('qstn_id');
      $ans =  $values['stu_answer']  =  $this->input->post('ans'); 

      $testArr=array_combine($id,$ans);

      $arr=[];

      foreach ($testArr as $key => $value) 
      {
        $arr[]=array('stu_ans_id'=>$key,'stu_answer'=>$value);
      }


        $this->Common_model->insert_answer('student',$arr);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message_name' , 'Your Data is Inserted');
        redirect('Quiz/tot_marks');
```

}

It's my controller...

```
public function insert_answer($table, $arr)
    {

        $result = $this->db->insert_batch($table, $arr);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();

    }
```

this is my model

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: if you got `stu_answer` array then you can encode it and store it.

Comment: Its already inserted but checkbox values are not inserted, which shows an array to string conversion error.

Comment: wheres your insert code?

Comment: use JSON encode/decode for array

Comment: please check my post I edited again...

Answer (score 1):

Use json_encode php function to convert array into string format and insert it to Database.